# Javascript date comparison issues with datejs

Tags: javascript, datejs

I have a date object, but the isAfter function in the API of datejs is not working. I opened the js library and cannot find any mention of it in there. I downloaded the latest version from dateJS site. Can anyone advise? Is there another method I should be using?

I am basically trying to compare a date to the current date, and see if it is less than 1 min before, less than 1hr before, less than 1 day before etc.

My code is:

```
function GetCleverDateString(date) {

    // Just a moment ago <1 min
    // X minutes ago
    // X hours ago
    // Yesterday
    alert(date.toString()); // date is constructed via new Date(...); this alerts the full date string 

    var theDate = new Date(date.toString()); // was experimenting

    if (theDate.isAfter(Date.today().addMinutes(-1)))
    {
        return 'Just now';
    }

    if (theDate.isAfter(Date.today().addHours(-1)))
    {
        return 'Less than an hour ago';
    }


}
```

I notice the version in their SVN has these methods. Perhaps I can get that? I don't know how though.

Comment: Relevant?: http://code.google.com/p/datejs/issues/detail?id=76

Comment: Are you using a regionalized version of datejs? If not try this .. http://code.google.com/p/datejs/source/browse/trunk/build/date-en-GB.js?r=145

Answer (score 6):

Okay turns out that the API doesn't match up to the actual JS on the download at all. You have to go to this url to get the latest version:

http://code.google.com/p/datejs/source/browse/trunk/#trunk%2Fbuild

Click the file you want

Then right click 'view raw file' and save as. This is the latest version.